# Be Alerted When SystemUIServer Restarts

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos

I need to be able to be alerted either when SystemUIServer terminates, or when it launches, preferably terminates.  The notification NSWorkspaceDidTerminateApplicationNotification isn't posted when launchd restarts it.  Is there some way I can be alerted?

--firen

Answer (score 1):

If you can find the pid for SystemUIServer, you could monitor it with a kqueue using the EVFILT_PROC and NOTE_EXIT flags.